# gnome-terminal does not display UTF-8 characters correctly (zsh)

Tags: zsh, utf-8

I installed zsh v5.8.1 on Ubuntu 22.04.3. And my gnome-terminal looks like so:

[image]

the symboles do not seem to be right. Whats wrong?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the command and the corresponding output to the question *as text*  and format it as a code block *in addition* to the image. What symbols do you expect there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terminal is decoding the character from bytes correctly, but you don't have any fonts that would support it. U+F489 is in the "private use" area (i.e. without a standard meaning), but it looks like it's typically used by [Nerd Fonts](https://www.nerdfonts.com/font-downloads) (to be shown as a "Terminal" icon). Make sure you have the appropriate patched font installed.